# System.currentTimeMillis() Race Condition

Tags: java, spring, guid

Can using `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a unique identifier in a Java Spring Boot project lead to a race condition, where someone can hit the API at the same milisecond? What are the chances of this.

Is there a way to generate a unique identifier of certain length (16-18 charecters) as GUID is like 36 char long.

Comment: [`UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--)

Comment: Can it lead to a race condition? Absolutely yes (especially if the traffic is non-trivial). What are the chances of this? IMO, it doesn't matter as the idea of using millisecond as an id is bad if you cannot guarantee that there will be atmost one request for each millisecond (and adding distributed/multiple systems makes it wrose)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call it a race condition, but yes getting two requests at the same millisecond is possible. What are the chances? That depends on how it's used. If I *want* to make many requests per millisecond, I can. If I'm explicitly careful not to, that's possible too.

You probably want to use `UUID.randomUUID()`. Most databases support those natively, and can even generate them for you. They won't be significantly more expensive.

Of course, you could use a random number of similar size, and encode it in a different format. GUIDs use hexadecimal, which takes a lot of characters compared to something like base64.

Answer (score 0):

at a guess once you have a thousand concurrent users the chance is guaranteed.

why 16 characters? seems arbitrary. you could use a random number generator and keep a time out map and keep track of users that way I guess?

but why not just use the cookie session id that spring supports for this.

Comment: You are assuming this is about some kind of request or user id. Not saying that's wrong, but the OP hasn't actually said that.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of `System.currentTimeMillis()` says:

> Returns the current time in milliseconds.  Note that
> while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond,
> the granularity of the value depends on the underlying
> operating system and may be larger.  For example, many
> operating systems measure time in units of tens of
> milliseconds.

Even if you have millisecond granularity, collisions will occur with some frequency. For instance, suppose you have 10 users hitting the API in the same second. The chance of a particular request colliding is 10 / 1000 = 1%. If a collision causes a user-visible failure, that's likely intolerably high.

If you want something like `UUID.randomUUID`, only shorter, why not take inspiration from it? Here is its implementation:

```
    public static UUID randomUUID() {
        SecureRandom ng = Holder.numberGenerator;

        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[16];
        ng.nextBytes(randomBytes);
        randomBytes[6]  &= 0x0f;  /* clear version        */
        randomBytes[6]  |= 0x40;  /* set to version 4     */
        randomBytes[8]  &= 0x3f;  /* clear variant        */
        randomBytes[8]  |= (byte) 0x80;  /* set to IETF variant  */
        return new UUID(randomBytes);
    }
```

So basically, it just has a `SecureRandom` somewhere, asks it for 16 random bytes, massages these into the form of the UUID standard. You don't need a UUID standard, and you need less than 16 bytes. So why not do this?

```
    class MyRandomIdGenerator {
        static SecureRandom generator = new SecureRandom();

        static long nextId() {
            return generator.nextLong();
        }
    }
```

The longest `long` is 19 characters in decimal notation. You can use hex notation to get it down to 16, or store it in binary format in 8 bytes.

If the negative IDs bother you, you can always discard the highest bit with

```
return generator.nextLong() >>> 1;
```